# I want to change a cookies value when heading to another page?

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, setcookie

In PHP i will set the cookie and give it a value that's a variable, when the user enters their name they will be taken to another page but when they get to that new page i need the value of that cookie changed to what name they entered, could someone show me how this would be done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first page (index.php) for example

```
<?php
//check if the form is submitted
if($_POST['update_name']){
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
        //name filed is filled

        //define cookie expire time
        $expire = time()+60*60*24*30; #cookie will expire after a month
        //set the cookie
        setcookie("name", $_POST['name'], $expire);
        //take the user to another page
        header("location: page_two.php");
    }else{
    //form was submitted with empty name field
    //show error message
    echo "Name is required";
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="update_name" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in page_two.php

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["name"];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass the name to `setcookie`, which will overwrite any previous value stored.

```
setcookie("name", $name, time() + 60 * 60 * 24); // expires in a day
```